# Sliding one element in, while sliding one out? Positioning messed up? The elements are covering themselves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just got a quick question about some jQuery/CSS placement. I'm trying to achieve the effect found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ggfA6/8/), but with my CSS, the placement of the objects is totally messed up. I think I've got the idea of the situation, I just can't seem to find a way to get my CSS to work. Anything you've got that can help, I'd love to hear it. Thanks in advance!

Everything I have so far can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v2LNn/).

JS:

```
function validate(form) {
var user = form.username.value;
var pass = form.password.value;

if(user === "test") {
    if(pass === "pass") {
        var hideoptions = {"direction" : "left",  "mode" : "hide"};
        var showoptions = {"direction" : "left", "mode" : "show"};

        $("#loginView").toggle("slide", hideoptions, 1000);
        $("#loginView2").toggle("slide", showoptions, 1000);
    } else {
        alert("nope");
    }
} else {
    alert("nope 2");
}
```

}

Nothing I do seems to work, and I really hope you can help!

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you ultimately want to do with it? Is it for sliding images, pictures, colors, etc?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly needs to slide and what is the look you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the title is a bit longer than most SO questions should have

Comment: one reason it might not work is that in jsfiddles, inline event handlers don't really work properly. I'll update it to try to get rid of those

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/v2LNn/8/ seems to work if you enter test and pass, and I barely changed anything (just got rid of inline handler)

Comment: So sorry for the rough context of the question! I'm new to Stackoverflow, and it has a lot more requirements for posting and it overall confuses me. What I want to achieve is a have different view points (so far a login screen '#loginView' and a screen for viewing files (not yet completed) '#loginView2'. I want it to be so if you have the correct password and username, it will slide from one view to the next. Meaning that the layout would be the same, such as the header, but the text would slide out to the left - with the header, a new one is in place. It would slide from the login view to the

Comment: file viewing view. Imagine a long line of frames, with you only able to view one at a time. You then push to the left all of the frames, creating almost a 'timeline' of view points. @TimSPQR

Comment: @MCSharp I couldn't add you above, I wanted to make sure you saw this. :)

Comment: Did you saw my answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have figured it out! Instead of using the .toggle() function, I simply just had to animate the change of the left margin! Thanks for all the support!

Answer (score 1):

I think the main mistake you did in your fiddle is "Missing to activate the Jquery UI". Becuase the effect you mentioned in your code is comes under the UI Jquery. Also some of the login functionality you missed there. I have modified and simplified your code and is working fine now. Check my fiddle below.

```
 $('.largeBtn').click(function(){  

if($('#username').val() == "test") {
    if($('#password').val() == "pass") {   
        var hideoptions = {  "direction" : "left",  "mode" : "hide"};
        var showoptions = {"direction" : "right","mode" : "show"};

        $("#loginView").toggle("slide", hideoptions, 1000);
        $("#loginView2").toggle("slide", showoptions, 1000);
    } else {
        alert("nope");
    }
} else {
    alert("nope 2");
}
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2LNn/10/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should solve your issue
Please have a look at this fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnypmody/p9Puk/)

> Note : For animations in jQuery you also need to import
>   **jquery-ui.js**

let me know if want me to elaborate

```
$(".largeBtn").click(function () {
 var user = login.username.value;
 var pass = login.password.value;

 if (user === "test") {
     if (pass === "pass") {

         // Set the effect type
         var effect = 'slide';

         // Set the options for the effect type chosen
         var hideoptions = {
             direction: 'left'
         };
         var showoptions = {
             direction: 'right'
         };

         $('#loginView').toggle(effect, hideoptions, 1000);
         $('#loginView2').toggle(effect, showoptions, 1000);

     } else {
         alert("nope");
     }
 } else {
     alert("nope 2");
 }
})
```

and also need to hide the second div content using css by default

```
#loginView2 {
position: absolute;
display: none;
}
```

Comment: That returns this - http://gyazo.com/49e83451f201e442eb178db9384fa213 - in the web browser. For kicks, I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.4. The site is being assembled in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 and is being viewed in Firefox 30.0. The jQuery - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js and the jQuery UI - http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js I will edit the JSFiddle to be updated to what I have now. @Suresh Ponnukalai JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2LNn/11/